# How to reference another file (i.e. png or jpg) in another directory in Python3?

Tags: python, path, assets

I'm using VS Code to program in **Python**. Instead of copying and pasting an image (or any other type of file) from one directory to the same directory my .py file is located in, I want to **reference that image** instead even if it's **in a different directory**. Or, at least, make that directory's path accessible from my program.

This is how my folders are structured.

```
- MainFolder
    - AssetsFolder
          - image.jpg
    - file.py
```

I tried:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\User\myname\MainFolder\AssetsFolder\')
```

But it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, you need to use relative directories.
In this case, to access `image.jpg` from `file.py`, you will need to use the path, `AssetsFolder/image.jpg`.

In order to access a higher directory, use `../`.  For example, if the file locations were swapped (`file.py` inside of `AssetsFolder` and `image.jpg` inside of `MainFolder`), you would need to use the path, `../image.jpg`.